# Array Vacio Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

No es un error, pero quisiera que no se mostrasen el registro que se levanta, ya que no tiene `precio` ni una `tienda` asignada. ya que el detalle es que cada `producto` pertenezca a una `tienda` y estos a su ves modificaron el precio a su conveniencia, por eso solo deveria mostrarse el producto que ya tenda precios modificado unicamente por dicha tienta.

```
    public function rproducto(){
        $ti=2;
        $li=\App\Modelo\Products::with(["moneda",
        "precio"=>function($q) use($ti){
           $q->where("codTienda",$ti);
        },
        "tienda"=>function($q) use($ti){
           $q->where("Codigo",$ti);
        }])->get();
        return $li;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si invierto la consulte, en lugar de buscar el produco, busco por tienda no tengo forma de cargar la moneda en la que deberia distribuirse el producto

```
public function rproducto(){
    $ti=2;
    $li=\App\Modelo\Products::with(["producto"=>function($q){
        //$q->moneda();
    }])->find($ti);
    return $li;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Toda consulta sql que no traiga resultado va estar vacia por lo tanto esta bien que traiga el precio y tienda vacio.

lo que puedes hacer es validar en la funcion **rproducto** que dichos campos no esten vacios.

ejemplo:

```
public function rproducto()
{
    $ti=2;
    $li=\App\Modelo\Products::with(["moneda",
    "precio"=>function($q) use($ti){
        $q->where("codTienda",$ti);
    },
    "tienda"=>function($q) use($ti){
        $q->where("Codigo",$ti);
    }])->get();

    if(count($li['precio']) === 0 || count($li['tienda']) === 0 ){
        // puedes retornar un array vacio o generar un error
        return array();
    }
    return $li;
}
```